# Compose - How to make ProgressBar determinate in code?

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, android-jetpack-compose

In some cases I need to display indeterminate progress bar and then convert it to determinate in a specific case. How can this be done in compose?

**Example**

When downloading a file. I need to display an indeterminate progress bar as a start and then convert it to a determinate progress bar

In Views this can be done with the `setIndeterminate()` . function

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `LinearProgressIndicator` or `CircularProgressIndicator` without the `progress` parameter, it is indeterminate .

You can use something like:

```
var indeterminate by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

if (indeterminate) {
    LinearProgressIndicator()
} else {
    LinearProgressIndicator(progress = animatedProgress)
}
```

[image]